# Error on configuration of two object-store service on keystone

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, keystone

Following ["OpenStack installation guide for Ubunut 12.04 LTS"](http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/)  have configured a network of virtual machine with keystone e swift services. I have configured swift to use keystone service for authentication.All work perfectly. The problem has arisen when trying to configure a second swift service on keystone. On key stone i have create the two swift services called "swift" and "swift2" both with type property set set to the value "object-store". I set the endpoints for both services: `"http://proxyserver1:8080/v1/AUTH_%(tenant_id)s"` for first swift service and `"http://proxyserver2:8080/v1/AUTH_%(tenant_id)s"` for the second. For each swift service i have created a user with role "admin" and both belonging to same tenant "service". When i try to authenticate a user on keystone using:

```
curl -s -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "service", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "swift", "password": "PASSWORD"}}}' -H 'Content-type: application/json' http://identity-manager:5000/v2.0/tokens
```

I receive a response with a incorrect `serviceCatalog` array. It contains only two endpoints: endpoints for keystone itself and one for an object-store service. So is missing one object-store service endpoint. Moreover the endpoits for the only object-store service returned is wrong because is a property mix of the two object-store service:

```
{
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "adminURL": "http://proxyserver2:8080",
      "region": "regionOne",
      "internalURL": "http://proxyserver1:8080/v1/AUTH_74eb7b8a36f64105a7d77fe00a2b6d41",
      "id": "0d30428e6a2d4035baf1c84401c8ff1b",
      "publicURL": "http://proxyserver1:8080/v1/AUTH_74eb7b8a36f64105a7d77fe00a2b6d41"
    }
  ],
  "endpoints_links": [],
  "type": "object-store",
  "name": "swift2"
}
```

My question is whether it is possible to configure two swift cluster on keystone. If the answer is yes, where I could have been wrong?